# Large parquet file really slow to query

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

I've created a parquet file from a directory of csv files. There are more than 205 million rows of data.

```
from pyarrow import csv, parquet
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

csvDir = 'my_csv_dir'

fields = [
   ('workId',pa.string()),
   ('authorId',pa.string())
]

schema = pa.schema(fields)
dataset = ds.dataset(csvDir,format="csv",schema=schema)
table = dataset.to_table()
print(table.num_rows,'rows')
parquet.write_table(table, 'my_parquet.parquet')
```

Here's code to get info about the parquet file.

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile('my_parquet.parquet')
print(parquet_file.metadata)
print(parquet_file.schema)
```

Here's the output.

```
<pyarrow._parquet.FileMetaData object at 0x7f79d36cb8b0>
  created_by: parquet-cpp-arrow version 8.0.0
  num_columns: 2
  num_rows: 205841002
  num_row_groups: 4
  format_version: 1.0
  serialized_size: 1429
<pyarrow._parquet.ParquetSchema object at 0x7f795a15e500>
required group field_id=-1 schema {
  optional binary field_id=-1 workId (String);
  optional binary field_id=-1 authorId (String);
}
```

Simple queries run really slow.

Here's one way I query:

```
import duckdb
print(duckdb.query("select count(*) from'my_parquet.parquet'").fetchall())
print(duckdb.query("select workId,authorId from'my_parquet.parquet' where workId = 'W2137422493'").fetchall())
```

Here's the timed run:

```
time python query.py

[(205841002,)]
[('W2137422493', 'A1461130442 A2023515231')]

real    0m10.690s
user    0m30.743s
sys     0m1.277s
```

Here's another way I tried querying.

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
dataset = ds.dataset('my_parquet.parquet')
print(dataset.files)
print(dataset.schema.to_string())
print(dataset.to_table(filter=ds.field('workId') == 'W2137422493').to_pandas())
```

Here's the timed output of that.

```
['my_parquet.parquet']
workId: string
authorId: string

        workId                 authorId

0  W2137422493  A1461130442 A2023515231

real    1m23.121s
user    1m23.197s
sys     0m48.689s
```

I've not been able to figure out how to index workId to speed up the query. I've read that there's such a thing as a column index but it seems like that's for range searching which is not what I'm trying to do.

How can I speed up this simple query?

Update: I turned the workId field into an integer field by removing the "W" and sorted all the data. Assuming Arrow reads the files in name order, all of the data should be in numeric order. No speedup in query time was seen so I don't get how to parquet to create a column index.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that parquet isn't a database and it's not designed for fast searching on string fields. Maybe column indexing and row groups are needed and maybe I need integer ranges.

Comment: You already found the answer. The best you can do with parquet files is to use numeric columns (like you did in your update) and increase the number of row groups (or, equivalently, specify a smaller row_group_size in parquet.write_table). Because each row group stores the minimum and maximum values of each column in its metadata, by increasing the number of row groups you improve the performance of your query (the search will skip row groups where the queried value is out of range). This mimic the behavior of a column index in a database, which would be a better tool for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried writing sorted Parquet files with Spark using bucketing ?
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-bucketing.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to partition your data into a multifile dataset instead of having it all in one file.

See the docs https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#writing-partitioned-data

Instead of `parquet.write_table(table, 'my_parquet.parquet')`

You should do

```
part = ds.partitioning(
    pa.schema([("workId", pa.string())]), flavor="hive"
)

ds.write_dataset(table, "partitioned_dataset", format="parquet", partitioning=part)
```

Subsequently, when you load the data you'll do:

```
dataset = ds.dataset("partitioned_dataset", format="parquet",
                 partitioning="hive")
```

This will make it so that each `workId` gets its own directory such that when you query a particular `workId` it only loads that directory which will, depending on your data and other parameters, likely only have 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is, but I suspect incredibly slow I/O or some evil interaction. Using Julia instead of Python, I just created a random dataset the size of yours:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(i1 = rand(Int32, 100000000), i2 = rand(Int32, 100000000));
julia> DuckDB.register_data_frame(con, df, "df")
julia> DuckDB.execute(con, "copy (select * from df) to 'xyz.parquet' (FORMAT 'parquet')")
```

Then with a clean restart of Julia I get this (even with recompilation delays). I know that Julia itself is vastly faster than Python, but the time should all be spent inside duckDB.

Do you perhaps have an old version of duck? What kind of disk are you using? How big is your data file? How long does `md5sum` take to process your data file? (my answers: DuckDB 0.4.1, Julia 1.7.3, 764MB, 1.4s).

```
julia> @time DuckDB.execute(con, "select count(*)/1e6 from 'xyz.parquet'")
  0.343190 seconds (492.16 k allocations: 26.770 MiB, 3.39% gc time, 89.95% compilation time)
1×1 DataFrame
 Row │ (count_star() / 1000000.000000) 
     │ Float64                         
─────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1 │                           100.0
julia> @time DuckDB.execute(con, "select count(*)/1e6 from 'xyz.parquet'")
  0.343190 seconds (492.16 k allocations: 26.770 MiB, 3.39% gc time, 89.95% compilation time)
1×1 DataFrame
 Row │ (count_star() / 1000000.000000) 
     │ Float64                         
─────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1 │                           100.0
julia> @time DuckDB.execute(con, "select * from 'xyz.parquet' where i2 = 2020759595")
  1.060725 seconds (47 allocations: 2.469 KiB)
1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ i1           i2         
     │ Int32        Int32      
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │ -1460818637  2020759595
```

In previous experiments, I found that sorting data kind of like this could make massive improvements in speed, but only because I used the Z-standard compression and I had a lot of repeated values. I got 300:1 compression (from 1GB to 3MB) and my query times got very fast. For this data set, the compressed size after sorting on `i1` was just under 700MB and query times were nearly unchanged.